# Transform my ArrayList into a String[] of a certain attribute JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` and I need to get every element's name and put it into a table of strings: `result[]`.
I tried this:

```
for (Baby baby:babyList){
    result[i]=baby.getName();
}
```

It doesnt seem to work any idea?

Comment: you are iterating babylist but assigning every element to same index of array - i.e it keeps overwriting till last element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about with a stream

```
String[] result = babyList.stream()
        .map(Baby::getName)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Note: `toArray` is since Java 11

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't work because `i` is not defined or is not being incremented. You're using an enhanced for loop where there is no index. Instead, try this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < babyList.size(); i++) {
    result[i] = babyList.get(i).getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `i=0` outside the loop. Then do: (assuming you have already defined the array `result`)

```java
int i=0;
for (Baby baby:babyList){
    result[i++]=baby.getName();
}
```